# Not able to run android application on device from eclipse

Tags: android

I have android application that I need to debug using eclipse. When I right click on the project and say debug as Android Application the application doesnt get installed.

See the logs and details below:

```
[2011-11-03 20:08:20 - Test1] Android Launch!
[2011-11-03 20:08:20 - Test1] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-03 20:08:20 - Test1] Performing com.fib.test.Test1Activity activity launch
[2011-11-03 20:08:20 - Test1] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
[2011-11-03 20:08:20 - Test1] Uploading Test1.apk onto device 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
[2011-11-03 20:08:20 - Test1] Installing Test1.apk...
```

Details:

OS: Ubuntu

Android Developement Tools: version 14.0

Debug mode is enabled on the device. This used to work a few days back. It stopped working recently.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html ? Tried to uninstall application manually from device?

Comment: my device is getting detected fine. I'm able to install the application through adb (adb install <apk>) from commandline. It is only through eclipse that it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded my eclipse to Helios and re-installed the ADT plugin. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting the adb connection and sometimes your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it helps to uninstall the app manually from the phone first.

Answer (score 0):

first try:

```
adb devices
```

to see if the device is present (even is connected with cable it might not be 'connected')

other thing you can do is

```
adb stop
```

and afftet that

```
adb start
```

this will restart , and I think will work fine after that

Comment: go to your android device, in settings - application - development - and then uncheck and check the USB Debuging

Comment: one more note, are you sure that you cable is ok ? , cause it might be a hardware issue